# How to only show logged in user's posts to user in Laravel Voyagers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I had installed fresh Laravel project and added the Laravel Voyagers Package in it.

Later I had created the Product table with id, title, user_id and created its respective BREAD.

User can have many Products. So for Relationship, I had defined in product table that Every product BelongsTo User.
Its working fine till here. But I when I logged in as user then I am able to see all products instead of my assigned products only.

How I can manage this thing in laravel voyagers.

Comment: you need to add condition in product list query like App\Product::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();

Comment: can you guide me in which exact file of voyagers? There is no product Controller for this @sandy

Answer (score 0):

try use :

```
 $product = Product::all()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

or :

```
 $product = \DB::table('Product')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
```